# How to display decimal points?

Tags: c++, class, terminal

I have tried everything. This terminal im working on when I put something like 1/5 = a  and try to diplay the a, it will say it's 0. Or even if I try 25/10 which is suppose to be 2.5, it displays 2. I tried using float, double, int. Everything. Please help me.

Comment: Post your code, and maybe we can help.  Otherwise, we have you use our psychic powers to deduce your problem.

Answer (score 4):

1, 5, 25, 10 are integers, so calculating with them will produce integer results. Try `double x = 1.0/5.0` and `double y = 25.0/10.0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a;
    a=(float)1/5;
    cout << a << endl;
}
```